# removing styles with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this list defined in a HTML5 file, and I want to know if it is possible when I click on a `<li>`  to add the class `default` and remove it from the others `<li>` using JQuery

```
 <ul id="ul-graellatab-list" class="tabs">
   <li><a href="#" class="tabs_menu default">Temperature</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="tabs_menu">Humidity</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="tabs_menu">Pressure</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#ul-graellatab-list li").click(function() {
     $("#ul-graellatab-list li.default").removeClass("default");
     $(this).addClass("default");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$("#ul-graellatab-list > li").click(function() {
     $("#ul-graellatab-list > li").removeClass("default");
     $(this).addClass("default");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ul-graellatab-list li').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
      $('li.default').removeClass('default');
      $(this).addClass('default');
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: There's no need to use each here. You can bind the click event to the list items directly